# Better way to get a List of JTextField from a JFrame using Swing API

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm interacting with a 3rd party tool in swing and this tool generate the input dynamically based on the wizard steps. I would like to get the collections of `JTextField` of a `JFrame` to execute this wizard in my application.

**EDITED:** As a proof of concept, here is what I've coded to get a list of JTextField but I think is too much code. I just was wondering to find a better/standard solution using the swing API. I also edited the final code to be complaint with the Stack Overflow requirements (There we go). Thanks for all your suggestions.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowInputTexts extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // --------------------> begin of the relevant code <--------------------------------
    private void loadChields(final JComponent component, final Set<JComponent> chields) {
        for (final Component chieldComp : component.getComponents()) {
            if (chieldComp instanceof JComponent) {
                final JComponent chield = (JComponent) chieldComp;
                chields.add(chield);
                loadChields(chield, chields);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<JTextField> getInputComponents(final JFrame frame) {
        final List<JTextField> fields = new LinkedList<>();
        final Set<JComponent> chields = new HashSet<>();
        for (final Component chield : frame.getComponents()) {
            loadChields((JComponent) chield, chields);
        }
        for (final JComponent chield : chields) {
            if (chield instanceof JTextField) {
                fields.add((JTextField) chield);
            }
        }
        return fields;
    }
   // --------------------> end of the relevant code <--------------------------------


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ShowInputTexts dialog = new ShowInputTexts();
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void showInputFiels(JFrame frame) {
        for (JTextField input: getInputComponents(frame)) {
            System.out.println(input);
        }
    }

    public ShowInputTexts() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel("Input 1");
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField("");
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel("Input 2");
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField("");
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton("Submit");
        jButton2.addActionListener(e -> showInputFiels(this));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(28, 28, 28).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(jLabel1).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 256, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(jLabel2).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jButton2).addComponent(jTextField2)))).addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(23, 23, 23).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jLabel1).addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jLabel2).addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jButton2).addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        pack();
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;

}
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I am not at all clear what your specific question is or really what you're trying to do. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please consider seriously fleshing out this problem in greater and clearer detail for us.

Comment: What third party tool?

Comment: Essentially I just need get the input objects collections of the current step. I think the best way to do it is interact with all the child components and get what I'm interested. I just don't know if there is an specific API to get it done or if I have to do it manually (swing is not my area).

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *".. but I think is too much code"* I know it is not an MCVE. That is an uncompilable code snippet. An MCVE contains the class definition, the imports, and a main method - basically everything that is needed to compile without change & put the GUI on-screen. I think you did not read the links carefully, or if you did, you did not understand them. Read them again now. If there is anything in them you don't understand, ***ask.***

Comment: BTW, 1) there are tons of code snippet without main and imports on stackoverflow, I just tried to make it simple. Requirement is a requirement, so let's do it. 2) The third party tool I can't mention and put the code here (privacy and NDA, sorry)